# HOw to run multiple applications in play framework on the same port

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play Framework. I am using Play 2.0.2 and I want to run multiple applications on Play on the same port.

It should be like 
`http://localhost:9000/Project1/(controller)` & `http://localhost:9000/Project2/(controller)`

I have found that you can run it on different ports but found nothing regarding running it on the same port.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can't run two applications on the same port and it's not only Play's problem.

Use [frontend HTTP server](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/HTTPServer) to proxy applications. If you have to run only java apps then [nginx](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/HTTPServer) will be good choice, if you need to work also with PHP systems depending on Apache specific features you can use [Apache proxy](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/HTTPServer) as well.

In general: you need to set the server to listen on port 80 and then add a Server Block (Virtual Host in Apache) for each application using some pseudo domains like `http://app1.loc`, `http://app2.loc`, etc add them to your `hosts` file, to make them available in your system. Next configure each Server Block to be a proxy for application on different ports (nginx):

```
server {
  server_name app1.loc www.app1.loc;
    listen 80;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9021;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:9021/ http://app1.loc/;
    }
}
```

and then start your first app at port 9021.

Do the same for other application(s), each time using other port.

Finally to make sure, that you always running the app1 on required port 9021 write a bash script (or bat file in windows) which will run it always with the same settings i.e. `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
play "~run 9021";
```

Comment: nginx can handle php just fine, for example with a php-fpm.

Comment: Right, anyway some old PHP systems depends much on some Apache specific features (at least out of the box) so I don't like (personally) 'fighting' with nginx :) Instead I preffer to use separate machines for the servers or... proxying apache with nginx :)

Comment: true, but I wouldn't go so far as to recommend apache whenever php is involved. The nginx documentation has an extensive list of application specific configurations.

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible with play alone, since each application runs in its own process and there can only be one process listening on one port at one time. What you can do is run your play applications on ports 9001 and 9002 and then run a server like nginx on port 9000 and configure it to route requests for the different URLs to your play applications.

See this example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html
The only difference to your case is that you would have one `server {...}` block with two `location` blocks in it. It would look something like:

```
upstream play1 {
      server localhost:9001;
}

upstream play2  {
      server localhost:9002;
}

server {
    listen       localhost:9000;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/www.example.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/log/www.example.error.log;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    ## send requests to play1 ##
    location /Project1/ {
        proxy_pass  http://play1;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    ## send requests to play2 ##
    location /Project2/ {
        proxy_pass  http://play2;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wanted to confirm one thing. There will be only one server instance or two (one for each project).

Comment: you only need one server instance, unless you want multiple virtual hosts like project1.example.com and project2.example.com

Comment: @KimStebel - this isn't working correct for me. I can request index action but the assets aren't loaded (app tries to load css from http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css. I would expect http://127.0.0.1:9000/Project1/assets/stylesheets/main.css or direct from http://127.0.0.1:9001/assets/stylesheets/main.css) I'm using Play 2.1 Java version.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to host several applications in the same server or load balance several instances of your application for scalability or fault tolerance, you can use a front-end HTTP server.
Note that using a front-end HTTP server will never give you better performance than using Play server directly.You can have a look on this :[How to set-up a front-end HTTP server for Play 2 Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/HTTPServer)