# Can I have multiple web modules in play framework application?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Play Framework 2.4 (Scala). I want to make a modular play application, where each module has its own web interface. 
By this I mean that each module contains its own controllers, models and views.

This is different from this ([HOw to run multiple applications in play framework on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117452/how-to-run-multiple-applications-in-play-framework-on-the-same-port)) stack overflow question below because for mine each module does not have to run as an independent application.

I tried using the "multidomain-seed" application
on activator (https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-seed#master), but it only seems to run one web module at a time.
In the console I also get the error: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind". To get this all I did was download the project and use activator to run it.

Is it possible to have a play application with multiple web modules?

Comment: Yes, https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the admin example in that link and got the same error I was getting before (the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind" error). I also tried this (https://github.com/gnorr/basic_play_scala) project, with the same result. I'm using activator 1.3.6

Comment: if you did all right, probably there is another process left using same port.

Comment: I can confirm that the project you linked runs with no errors.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured out a bit more. The project runs OK using "activator run", but when I run "activator ui", it fails. Activator ui generates the "play-fork-run.sbt" file in the project directory. However in this file, the version of  the "sbt-fork-run-plugin" plugin is 2.3.7, which no longer exists. When I update this to 2.4.0 I get the "Address already in use" error.