# Running application multiple times on same port play framework

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play framework. I have an application which uses Play 2.2.2. When multiple users simultaneously access my application, the link is not working (shows as loading). I came across a similar link in stack overflow ([HOw to run multiple applications in play framework on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117452/how-to-run-multiple-applications-in-play-framework-on-the-same-port))

As per the link, one application is routed to port 9021. How to route all concurrent applications to be opened in a different ports using load balancing. Please help me to understand.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a reverse proxy, you can have a try on nginx, just put your play apps behind nginx.